# How to pass an Array input to a dynamic SELECT query inside a Postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I am not able to use dynamic SELECT statements inside Postgres function to return a result set where the input parameter is an Array:

```
CREATE TYPE schema.emp_name_type as (
emp_name varchar);--just a single column to hold all employee names

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.emp_data2(
    i_emp_name schema.emp_name_type[])--input in array format
    RETURNS TABLE(emp_name character varying, emp_address character varying) --return the name and address
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 5000
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   V_ORDER_BY text;
   V_MAIN_QRY text;
BEGIN

   V_EMP_QRY:=
            $$ SELECT
a.emp_name,a.emp_address
 FROM schema.emp e
WHERE 1=1
AND e.emp_name in (select a.emp_name from unnest($$ || i_emp_name || $$ ) a)$$;--using unnest array in where condition

V_ORDER_BY := ' ORDER BY 1 ';

V_MAIN_QRY := V_EMP_QRY || V_ORDER_BY;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE V_MAIN_QRY;

RAISE NOTICE '%',V_MAIN_QRY;
END;
$BODY$;

--this is the calling mechanism
select * from schema.emp_data2
(array[row('John'),
row('Roy'),
row('James')]::schema.emp_name_type[]);
```

I am getting malformed array literal error while executing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for dynamic SQL here. You also don't need to unnest the array. You can use the `= ANY()` operator with the parameter.

You also don't need a special type for this. Declaring the parameter as `i_emp_name text[]` would work just fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.emp_data2(i_emp_name text[])--input in array format
    RETURNS TABLE(emp_name character varying, emp_address character varying) --return the name and address
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 5000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT a.emp_name, a.emp_address
    FROM schema.emp e
    WHERE e.emp_name = any(i_emp_name)
    ORDER BY 1;
  
END;
$BODY$;
```

By using a `text[]` parameter calling the function will be a lot simpler as well:

```
select * 
from schema.emp_data2(array['John','Roy','James']);
```

---

But if you really want to keep the (useless in my opinion) wrapper type, you still don't need dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.emp_data2(i_emp_name schema.emp_name_type[])--input in array format
    RETURNS TABLE(emp_name character varying, emp_address character varying) --return the name and address
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 5000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT a.emp_name, a.emp_address
    FROM schema.emp e
    WHERE e.emp_name in (select emp_name from unnest(i_emp_name))
    ORDER BY 1;
  
END;
$BODY$;
```

---

If you really need dynamic SQL then use bind parameters, don't concatenate input strings:

```
V_EMP_QRY := $$ 
  SELECT a.emp_name,a.emp_address
  FROM schema.emp e
  WHERE true
  AND e.emp_name = any ($1) $$;
```

Then use

```
return query execute v_emp_qry 
     using i_emp_name;
```

If you stick to the useless wrapper type, then you need to use the `$1` as a parameter for the `unnest()` in the sub-query of my second example: `in (select emp_name from unnest($1))`.

If you need to reference the same parameter multiple times, just use the `$1` multiple times.

Comment: This is just an example, the actual implementation requires the query to be dynamic as there are multiple unions that gets added based on the parameters. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @GoutamSahoo see my edit. But probably still don't need dynamic SQL. You can have multiple `return query` statements in your function. No real need for a UNION